How to do animation with react state array
I have objects in my useState
const [tasks,setTasks] = useState([{completed: true},{completed: false}])

I sorted it to make completed tasks be at the bottom.
<div>
  {tasks.map((elem) => (
    <div
      onClick={
        //Here I change completed to true if its false, so how do I make css animation like its falling down?
      }
    >
      {elem.name}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>;

I tried using shuffle or ReactCSSTransition but its deprecated and do not work. Any other libraries I can use may be?

Add a unique id to state.
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
 { id: 1, completed: true, name: "Task 1" },
 { id: 2, completed: false, name: "Task 2" },
]);

Complete code:
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
{ id: 1, completed: true, name: "Task 1" },
{ id: 2, completed: false, name: "Task 2" },
]);
const [updatedTasks, setUpdatedTasks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 if (updatedTasks.length > 0) {
   setTasks(updatedTasks);
   setUpdatedTasks([]);
 }
}, [updatedTasks]);

return (
 <div>
    {tasks.map((elem) => (
     <div
       onClick={() => {
         const updatedTask = tasks.map((task) =>
           task.id === elem.id
            ? { ...task, completed: !task.completed }
            : task
        );
        setUpdatedTasks(updatedTask);
      }}
    >
      <div className={elem.completed ? "" : "fall-down"}>{elem.name}</div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>

add css :
.fall-down {
   animation: fallDown 0.5s ease-out forwards;
 }

@keyframes fallDown {
  0% {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
100% {
  transform: translateY(50px);
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

